# Metainformation about SharePoint structures for typescript/JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, typescript, pnpjs

Hi all I think it is easier if I try to explain with an example.

So if I want to add a field using xml I need to populate the xml based on what data a field of an specific type can have. SharePoint has this enum values to define the `FieldKindType` and I am sure that internally it also check what are the properties available for each field type.

Is that info available anywhere? preferable for ts/js.

Comment: Are you trying to create a column using API (in SPFx)? or PowerShell?

Comment: on the client side with pnpjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PnP JS, you can import `FieldTypes` using below import statement:

```
import { FieldTypes } from "@pnp/sp/fields/types";
```

This enum has below values:

```
/**
 * Specifies the type of the field.
 */
export declare enum FieldTypes {
    Invalid = 0,
    Integer = 1,
    Text = 2,
    Note = 3,
    DateTime = 4,
    Counter = 5,
    Choice = 6,
    Lookup = 7,
    Boolean = 8,
    Number = 9,
    Currency = 10,
    URL = 11,
    Computed = 12,
    Threading = 13,
    Guid = 14,
    MultiChoice = 15,
    GridChoice = 16,
    Calculated = 17,
    File = 18,
    Attachments = 19,
    User = 20,
    Recurrence = 21,
    CrossProjectLink = 22,
    ModStat = 23,
    Error = 24,
    ContentTypeId = 25,
    PageSeparator = 26,
    ThreadIndex = 27,
    WorkflowStatus = 28,
    AllDayEvent = 29,
    WorkflowEventType = 30
}
```

**Documentation**: [SP PnP JS - Fields](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/fields/)